Java class using SikuliAPI not working after Windows update
After migrating to windows 11 a sikuli API code which was working fine in Windows 10 giving below error.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.sikuli.script.Mouse.setNotUseable(Mouse.java:410)
at org.sikuli.script.support.RobotDesktop.checkMousePosition(RobotDesktop.java:171)
at org.sikuli.script.support.RobotDesktop.smoothMove(RobotDesktop.java:141)
at org.sikuli.script.support.RobotDesktop.smoothMove(RobotDesktop.java:111)
at org.sikuli.script.Mouse.doMove(Mouse.java:317)
at org.sikuli.script.Mouse.move(Mouse.java:445)
at org.sikuli.script.Mouse.move(Mouse.java:390)
at org.sikuli.script.Screen.initScreens(Screen.java:164)
at org.sikuli.script.Screen.(Screen.java:198)
at Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: org.sikuli.script.SikuliXception: SikuliX fatal Error: System must be 64-Bit
at org.sikuli.script.support.Commons.(Commons.java:38)
... 10 more
Requesting your feedback.
